# Grouping Fixed Effects in fixest::etable()

Tags: r

When reporting the results from a `fixest` regression, I would like to economize on space by reporting multiple FEs in the same row. Looking at the `trade` data, here is a simple example:

```r
data(trade)
est_1 <- feols(Euros ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination + Product, trade)
```

`etable` produces what we would expect:

```r
> etable(est_1)
                                          est_1
Dependent Var.:                           Euros
                                               
log(dist_km)    -66,710,904.2*** (14,306,388.4)
Fixed-Effects:   ------------------------------
Origin                                      Yes
Destination                                 Yes
Product                                     Yes
_______________  ______________________________
S.E.: Clustered                      by: Origin
Observations                             38,325
R2                                      0.30324
Within R2                               0.05559
>
```

But what I'd like is for Origin and Destination and Product to just be one line with a name like "Origin, Destination, and Product FEs". But `group` (and `keep` and `drop`) seem not to apply to fixed effects:

```r
> etable(est_1, group = list("Origin and Destination and Product FEs" = "Origin|Dest|Product"))
                                                                 est_1
Dependent Var.:                                                  Euros
                                                                      
log(dist_km)                           -66,710,904.2*** (14,306,388.4)
Origin and Destination and Product FEs                              No
Fixed-Effects:                          ------------------------------
Origin                                                             Yes
Destination                                                        Yes
Product                                                            Yes
______________________________________  ______________________________
S.E.: Clustered                                             by: Origin
Observations                                                    38,325
R2                                                             0.30324
Within R2                                                      0.05559
```

That is, the new row made by `group` is all Nos *and* the old FE rows are still there. And if I try to trick `fixest` by repeating variable labels in `setFixest_dict`

```r
setFixest_dict(c(Origin = "Origin and Destination and Product FEs",
                 Destination = "Origin and Destination and Product FEs",
                 Product = "Origin and Destination and Product FEs"))
```

`etable` sensibly yells at me for non-unique values.

(The `trade` example I'm using here is probably a lousy one, but consider regressing wages on some treatment and a bunch of demographic fixed effects (age, sex, region, whatever). In that case, a Yes/No FE row called Demographic FEs (suitably explained in the table notes) would be great.)

Comment: I should note, one terrible solution is to move things from fixed effects to the plain RHS of the regression formula (`feols(Euros ~ log(dist_km) + factor(Origin) + factor(Destination) + factor(Product), trade)`). Then `group` in `etable` works as expected BUT that kills the huge speed benefits of `fixest`...

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to directly solve this via etable() - but what you could do is to demean your input data set via `fixest::demean()` and project out all fixed effects but one and then regress on the demeaned data with one remaining fixed effect. Eventually you could rename this remaining fe via `setFixest_dict()`.

Comment: I agree a simple solution should exist. Btw, please ask directly for new a feature (with use cases) on Github. If it's not a new estimator it's usually very easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

not very elegant, but you can work with the data.frame that `etable()` retunrs.

```r
library(fixest)
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
data(trade)
est_1 <- feols(Euros ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination + Product, trade)

# revemo all but first fixef_vars 
vars_to_remove <- est_1$fixef_vars[2:length(est_1$fixef_vars)]

# set a dict 
setFixest_dict(c(Origin = "Origin and Destination and Product FEs"))

# workd with data.frame
et <- etable(est_1)
et %>% filter(!rownames(et) %in% vars_to_remove)
#>                                                                  est_1
#> Dependent Var.:                                                  Euros
#>                                                                       
#> log(dist_km)                           -66,710,904.2*** (14,306,388.4)
#> Fixed-Effects:                          ------------------------------
#> Origin and Destination and Product FEs                             Yes
#> ______________________________________  ______________________________
#> S.E.: Clustered                                             by: Origin
#> Observations                                                    38,325
#> R2                                                             0.30324
#> Within R2                                                      0.05559
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be easily done with the Latex format using the `drop.section` argument, but this argument does not work for exports to `data.frame`s... (I shall overhaul `etable` in the future to make the two formats more in line...)

That said, it's fixed in the current github version so what is requested should be possible now:

```
etable(est_1, est_2, drop.section = "fixef", 
       extraline = list("O+D+P fixed-effects" = TRUE))
#>                                               est_1                          est_2
#> Dependent Var.:                               Euros                          Euros
#>                                                                                   
#> log(dist_km)        -66,710,904.2*** (14,306,388.4) -65,045,907.2*** (1,081,631.9)
#> (Intercept)                                         507,316,107.6*** (7,641,532.7)
#> O+D+P fixed-effects                             Yes                            Yes
#> ___________________  ______________________________ ______________________________
#> S.E. type                                by: Origin                       Standard
#> Observations                                 38,325                         38,325
#> R2                                          0.30324                        0.08623
#> Within R2                                   0.05559                             --
```

Another example with a different placement:

```
est_1 = feols(Euros ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination + Product, trade)
est_2 = feols(Euros ~ log(dist_km), trade)

etable(est_1, est_2, drop.section = c("fixef", "stats"), 
       extraline = list("_O+D+P fixed-effects" = c(TRUE, FALSE)))
#>                                               est_1                          est_2
#> Dependent Var.:                               Euros                          Euros
#>                                                                                   
#> log(dist_km)        -66,710,904.2*** (14,306,388.4) -65,045,907.2*** (1,081,631.9)
#> (Intercept)                                         507,316,107.6*** (7,641,532.7)
#> _______________      ______________________________ ______________________________
#> S.E. type                                by: Origin                       Standard
#> O+D+P fixed-effects                             Yes                             No
```

---

And here's a hacky yet automatic way using the custom definition of fit statistics:

```
fun_finding_fe = function(x) c("Yes", "No")[2 - all(c("Origin", "Destination", "Product") %in% x$fixef_vars)]

fitstat_register("my_fe", fun_finding_fe, "O+D+P fixed-effects")
etable(est_1, est_2, drop.section = "fixef", fitstat = ~ . + my_fe)
#>                                               est_1                          est_2
#> Dependent Var.:                               Euros                          Euros
#>                                                                                   
#> log(dist_km)        -66,710,904.2*** (14,306,388.4) -65,045,907.2*** (1,081,631.9)
#> (Intercept)                                         507,316,107.6*** (7,641,532.7)
#> ___________________  ______________________________ ______________________________
#> S.E. type                                by: Origin                       Standard
#> Observations                                 38,325                         38,325
#> R2                                          0.30324                        0.08623
#> Within R2                                   0.05559                             --
#> O+D+P fixed-effects                             Yes                             No
```